# Issues indexing data extract from xml

Tags: python, xml

I'm working with some XML data that will ultimately be loaded into a csv.  I am experiencing an issue with properly indexing the data when a element doesn't exist in an entry.  Below is a simple xml example of what I am working with

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <LASTNAME>Doe</LASTNAME>
        <FIRSTNAME>Jon</FIRSTNAME>
        <GENDER>M</GENDER>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <LASTNAME>Doe</LASTNAME>
        <FIRSTNAME>Jane</FIRSTNAME>
        <GENDER>F</GENDER>
        <HAIRCOLOR>Blonde</HAIRCOLOR>
    </entry>
</root>
```

The output I end up getting is as follows:

| LASTNAME | FIRSTNAME | GENDER | HAIRCOLOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | John | M | Blonde |
| Doe | Jane | F |  |

But the correct output should be:

| LASTNAME | FIRSTNAME | GENDER | HAIRCOLOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | John | M |  |
| Doe | Jane | F | Blonde |

So I seem to have an indexing problem where the first few times HAIRCOLOR (depending on the number of HAIRCOLOR elements are present on the page) is searched for, it goes down the XML until it finds one, but it should stop when it reaches the end of the entry.

Here's the code I am working with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ParseError
from xml.etree import ElementTree


bytes_ = '''
<root>
    <entry>
        <LASTNAME>Doe</LASTNAME>
        <FIRSTNAME>Jon</FIRSTNAME>
        <GENDER>M</GENDER>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <LASTNAME>Doe</LASTNAME>
        <FIRSTNAME>Jane</FIRSTNAME>
        <GENDER>F</GENDER>
        <HAIRCOLOR>Blonde</HAIRCOLOR>
    </entry>
</root>
'''
xpaths = [
    "./entry/LASTNAME",
    "./entry/FIRSTNAME",
    "./entry/GENDER",
    "./entry/HAIRCOLOR"
]

data = []

_fields = [
        {'text' : ''},
        {'text' : ''},
        {'text' : ''},
        {'text' : ''}
        ]

root = ET.fromstring(bytes_)


    for count in range(0,len(root.findall("./entry"))):
        
        for ele, xpath in enumerate(xpaths):
            try:
                attribs = list(root.findall(xpath)[count].attrib.keys())
                
                for attrib in attribs:
                    for i in _fields[ele].keys():
                
                        if attrib == i:
                            _fields[ele][i] = root.findall(xpath)[count].attrib[attrib]
                _fields[ele]["text"] =root.findall(xpath)[count].text
                

            except IndexError:
                _fields[ele]["text"]=''

            data.append(_fields[ele].values())
            data_list = [item for sublist in data for item in sublist]
        data.clear()
        print(data_list)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edited for clarity

Comment: I've added additional details to the OP.  Please let me know if I can provide any additional details.

Comment: Made more edits.  The code runs as is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your xpath `’./entry/HAIRCOLOR’` will match the HAIRCOLOR tag *wherever it is*, i.e. anywhere. You need to first find each `’./entry’` then for each entry look for HAIRCOLOR and the other tags within the entry. At the moment you’re looking in `root` For the sub-tags.

Comment: Thanks you for the advice.  I eventually realized through your comment to modify my xpath list by removing all of the "/entry"s.  A few other minor modifications later to accommodate for the change and it all works great.